# android:screenOrientation="sensor" doesn't work

Tags: android, orientation

I have read the document ，when I write `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` in ,that means the orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor. The orientation of the display depends on how the user is holding the device; it changes when the user rotates the device. Some devices, though, will not rotate to all four possible orientations, by default. To allow all four orientations, use "fullSensor".
But when I run the app, and rotates the device to landscape, the layout doesn't change, in the other word, `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: have you used `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`?

Comment: did that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Read read,

> "sensor" -
>   The orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor. The
>   orientation of the display depends on how the user is holding the
>   device; it changes when the user rotates the device. **Some devices,
>   though, will not rotate to all four possible orientations, by default**.
>   To allow all four orientations, **use "fullSensor"**.

.

> "fullSensor" -The orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor for any
>   of the 4 orientations. This is **similar to** "sensor" **except** this
>   allows any of the 4 possible screen orientations, **regardless** of
>   what the device will normally do (for example, some devices won't
>   normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables
>   those). Added in API level 9.

source - [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

example

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help,but i have changed to "fullSensor", and my minSdkVersion is 15, it doesn't work either.

Comment: And i didn't lock the system's orientation

Comment: @Ron do u use an emulator?

Comment: @Ron what about your other activities? where do you want that rotation ? you have set in your MainActivity is that the place you want it?